# Youtube Channel Embed with a sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed, youtube-channels

My client would like a youtube **channel** embed that has a playlist style sidebar (though she wants it to be the channel... not a playlist). Example:

[image]

**Is there a simple way to accomplish this?**

(yes, it must be Youtube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the [Youtube Custom Player](http://www.youtube.com/custom_player) for this. But I'm sure there's a better solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

[Youtube Feeder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-feeder/) plugin does exactly what you want.